Merge some specific cells in DataGrideView
I have two forms in my project
I save some data in form-1 and after saving this data in DataGirdView in table in form-2.
In form-1 I pay people in different months, every time I save the data in form-1 I have a new row in form-2 table for person.
Now I want to have one row for each person, but in the Get Money column I want to have the sum of the money I gave
Please see below picture
Thankyou.
Alimorad
enter image description here

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Hi  Community    I found solve my problem with other ways. thankyou
